# Why deleting a substring in a string doesn't work. Batch

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
@chcp 65001
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set test=qwert
goto start
:IsStrInStrFunc
setlocal
call set check=%%1:%2=%
echo %check%
endlocal
exit /b
:start
call :IsStrInStrFunc %test%, q
pause
```

The "check" variable must contain "wert". What's wrong?.......

Comment: Should be: `call set check=%%%1:%2=%%` *and* the invocation should be: `call :IsStrInStrFunc test, q`, that is, in the subroutine you want to use _the name_ of the **variable** test, _not_ its value...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set %check% to be "wert"

```
set check=%%1:%2=%
```

should be

```
set check=%test:~1%
```

For more info check command `help set` in Command Prompt

Comment: i want to remove "q" from word "qwert" using function

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example will assist you:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set _cp) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com"'
) Do For %%H In (%%G) Do Set "_cp=%%~nH"
If Not %_cp% Equ 65001 (Set "_cpc=TRUE"
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com" 65001 >NUL)

Set "test=qwert"

GoTo Start

:IsStrInStrFunc
Set "check=%~1"
Echo Before: %check%
SetLocal EnabledelayedExpansion
Set "check=!check:%~2=!"
EndLocal & Echo After: %check%
Exit /B

:Start
Call :IsStrInStrFunc "%test%" "q"

Pause
If Defined _cpc "%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com" %_cp% >NUL
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: Why i cant use both of parametrs(%1, %2) in one line?

Answer (score 0):

To do substring substitution on a variable, you need the variable*name*, not its value (see `set /?`), so your parameter in the `call` can't be `%test%` (which would pass the string `quert`), but must be `test`.
And as you are using delayed expansion anyway, why not using it?

```
@echo off
@chcp 65001
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "test=qwert"
goto start
:IsStrInStrFunc
setlocal
REM call set "check=%%%~1:%~2=%%"
set "check=!%~1:%~2=!"
echo %check%
endlocal
exit /b
:start
call :IsStrInStrFunc test q
```

PS: you don't need the `~` chars with your simple example, but they don't disturb either. Imagine you want to replace `a string`, you can simply do that with `call :IsStrInStrFunc test "a string"` (that's where the `~` *are* necessary. Good practice to include them anyway (just in case))